# Angular 1: Change title depending on current route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing

How do I change title that is displayed outside of a controller scope depending on current controller provided by router? Basically, I have mainMenu controller that is loaded when specific route is called. However, outside of the view, there is partial included which is a header. I want to change output inside of a header depending on the current route. I added code structure below:

index.html

```
<div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

/partials/header.html

```
<header ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
      <h1>{{ currentTitle }}</h1>
</header>
```

/partials/main-menu.html

```
<div ng-controller="MainMenuCtrl">

</div>
```

Router

```
var TaskApp = angular.module('TaskApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'taskAppControllers'
]);

TaskApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
      when('/main-menu', {
        templateUrl: "partials/main-menu.html",
        controller: "MainMenuCtrl"
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
      });
  }]);
```

Controllers:

```
var taskAppControllers = angular.module('taskAppControllers',[]);

taskAppControllers.controller('TaskAppCtrl',[function(){}]);
taskAppControllers.controller('DesktopCtrl',[function(){}]);

taskAppControllers.controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope','$http',
 function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('data/main-menu.json?' + Math.random()).success(function(data){
    $scope.mainMenuOptions = data;
  });
  $scope.currentTitle = "Main menu"
}]);

taskAppControllers.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$scope',
 function($scope){
   //
}]);
```

Comment: You can use this module https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb

Comment: Set the title on the $rootScope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add one more property with each route options, which will something like `title`

```
when('/main-menu', {
    templateUrl: "partials/main-menu.html",
    controller: "MainMenuCtrl",
    title: 'Main Page'
}).
```

Then place [**$routeChangeSuccess**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#$routeChangeSuccess)(it gets fired when route changes are succeeded) event inside `HeaderCtrl`, and then do grab current route object and get title from it and set it to `currentTitle` scope variable

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
    $scope.currentTitle = current.title;
});
```

Comment: I am kinda new to Angular, can you provide me more info or reference  about `$routeChangeSuccess` event?

Comment: Very well done, this works perfectly, I'll accept this answer as soon as Stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: @Kunok glad to know that.. Thanks :-)